# Guzzle HTTP Client and Shopify access token exception

Tags: php, shopify, access-token, webhooks, guzzle

I'm getting `Client error: POST https://testing-shop.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token resulted in a 400 Bad Request`while trying to exchange temporary code for access token in Shopify. I'm using the latest version of Guzzle HTTP client and in Chrome, Windows 8.1. What's even more weird is that it worked before.

```
$client = new Client();
    try{
    $response = $client->request(
        'POST', 
        "https://{$store}/admin/oauth/access_token",
        [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => $api_key,
                'client_secret' => $secret_key,
                'code' => $query['code']
            ]
        ]
    );
    }catch(Exception $e){
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

I also checked all my variables (`$api_key, $secret_key`)... and they're good which means they have values. What could be the problem here that I missed? TIA

EDIT:

It turned out to be the problem when registering the web hook .

```
$response = $client->request(
        'POST', 
        "https://{$store}/admin/webhooks.json",
        [
            'webhook' => [
                'topic' => 'app/uninstalled',
                'address' => 'http://example.com/shopify/uninstall',
                'format' => 'json'
            ]
        ]
    );
```

This code causes the error but I'm not though why.

Comment: No details on the error in the body of the response? The HTTP response of 400 alone doesn't give us much to go on. As for "it worked before" what changed?

Comment: no details on the error..  "Client error: `POST https://dmt-testing-shop.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: (truncated...) " that's the error message. Nothing's changed really.

Comment: I can't say for certain the Guzzle Exception would include that. Would look at `$response->getBody()` I think it is. Would be good to inspect raw header / response body. Similar to underlying cURL's `curl_getinfo `. If nothing has "really" changed it might be tied to CA certs?

Comment: The $response variable is null.

Comment: "The code parameter that is sent from Shopify can only be used a single time." True? HMAC with a timestamp component in the signing?

Comment: Yes true, and now it pointed to the the other code. see updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176277/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-silent-coder14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've got it. And it fits with having worked then stopped working:

> After July 1st 2018, apps will be required to use HTTPS webhook addresses.

See: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks

Comment: I'm getting this error while registering the webhook now: Unauthorized` response: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

Comment: Sounds like the key or access token is invalid :)

Comment: How should I pass the access token to the server? The documentation didn't mentioned something like that. :/

Comment: hmm looks like I have to set headers for the access token. Thank you for help!

Comment: Cool! Think we were both arriving there :)